# Laravel unknown controller action not found issue

Tags: laravel, routes, controller, action, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel 7.

Facing frustrated error,

> InvalidArgumentException Action App\Http\Controllers\CMSController@viewCmsPages not defined.

Successful:

```
redirect('/admin/view-cms-pages')
```

Fails:

```
redirect()->action('CMSController@viewCmsPages')
```

```
class CmsController extends Controller
{
    public function addCmsPage(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $data = $request->all();

            $cmspage->save();

            //return redirect('/admin/view-cms-pages')->with('flash_message_success','success');  

            //why fail...
            return redirect()->action('CMSController@viewCmsPages')->with('flash_message_success', 'success');
        }

        return view('admin.pages.add_cms_page');
    }

    public function viewCmsPages()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.view_cms_pages');
    }
}
```

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['adminlogin']], function () {

    Route::get('/admin/view-cms-pages','CmsController@viewCmsPages');

    //i try to add in this resource version also still can't call to 
        Route::resource('/admin/pages', 'CMSController');  
});
```

When I run `php artisan route:list`, I can see CMSController@viewCmsPages registered in the list.

Comment: I just tried it with a fresh Laravel 7 installation and it seems to be working properly for me.

Comment: hmm... weird then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your controller :

```
return redirect()->route('cms.view')->with('flash_message_success', 'success');
```

And then add name for the route on web.php :

```
// Add name for the route
Route::get('/admin/pages', 'CMSController@viewCmsPages')->name ('cms.view');
```

If you have a custome route, you should register it first, resource route only work for method [index,create,store,show,destory,edit,update]

Comment: Pls don't forget, to approve my answer